# Extract link thanks to pattern - python request

Tags: python, string, request

thanks to a request, I gathered all the text from a website. I am now facing a new issue;
At some times this appears in the text.

```
<I>Season 2021/2022</I><BR>
<IMG SRC="Excel.gif" BORDER="0" ALIGN="Absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="mmz4281/2122/I1.csv">Serie A</A> <FONT SIZE="1">(FT & HT results; match stats; match, total goals & AH odds)</FONT><BR>
<IMG SRC="Excel.gif" BORDER="0" ALIGN="Absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="mmz4281/2122/I2.csv">Serie B</A> <FONT SIZE="1">(FT & HT results; match stats;  match odds and total goals odds)</FONT><BR><BR>
```

What I would like to do, is to get just the HREF ("mmz4281/2122/I1.csv") from the first time "<>(stackoverflow is not rendering the I)Season" appears (i do not need the HREF for older seasons - talking about football matches).
Notice that the request returned quite a huge file.

Is there an easy way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This code will output the first url in the string:

```
string = """
<I>Season 2021/2022</I><BR>
<IMG SRC="Excel.gif" BORDER="0" ALIGN="Absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="mmz4281/2122/I1.csv">Serie A</A> <FONT SIZE="1">(FT & HT results; match stats; match, total goals & AH odds)</FONT><BR>
<IMG SRC="Excel.gif" BORDER="0" ALIGN="Absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="mmz4281/2122/I2.csv">Serie B</A> <FONT SIZE="1">(FT & HT results; match stats;  match odds and total goals odds)</FONT><BR><BR>
"""
num = string.find('HREF="')     #find index of HREF
url = string[num+6:]            #Extract string after HREF
num = url.find('">')            #Find index of ">
url = url[:num]                 #Extract string before ">
print(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use regular expressions for this. They can work wonders.

```py
import re

# The raw data
data = """
<I>Season 2021/2022</I><BR>
<IMG SRC="Excel.gif" BORDER="0" ALIGN="Absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="mmz4281/2122/I1.csv">Serie A</A> <FONT SIZE="1">(FT & HT results; match stats; match, total goals & AH odds)</FONT><BR>
<IMG SRC="Excel.gif" BORDER="0" ALIGN="Absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="mmz4281/2122/I2.csv">Serie B</A> <FONT SIZE="1">(FT & HT results; match stats;  match odds and total goals odds)</FONT><BR><BR>
"""

# Compile a Regular expression using the Single Line flag.
pattern = re.compile(r'<I>Season.*?HREF="(.*?)"', re.S)

# Search for a match of this pattern in the data
match = pattern.search(data)

# Print the matched group
print(match.group(1))
```

This outputs

```
mmz4281/2122/I1.csv
```

The regex broken down:

```
<I>Season   # Indication of a new Season
.*?         # Match any character lazily, including newline
HREF="      # Match HREF=" literally. Start of the HREF tag that we want.
(.*?)       # Group together a lazy match of any character.
"           # Match " literally. End of the HREF tag that we want.
```

Furthermore, if your file contains multiple separate seasons that you want to get href's for, then you can use `pattern.findall(data)` ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall)) to get a list of relevant href's.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse html, BeautifulSoup is the package you to be using. That's it sole purpose.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data = """
<I>Season 2021/2022</I><BR>
<IMG SRC="Excel.gif" BORDER="0" ALIGN="Absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="mmz4281/2122/I1.csv">Serie A</A> <FONT SIZE="1">(FT & HT results; match stats; match, total goals & AH odds)</FONT><BR>
<IMG SRC="Excel.gif" BORDER="0" ALIGN="Absmiddle">&nbsp;&nbsp;<A HREF="mmz4281/2122/I2.csv">Serie B</A> <FONT SIZE="1">(FT & HT results; match stats;  match odds and total goals odds)</FONT><BR><BR>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

# Find the first time "Season" appears
season = soup.find('i',text=re.compile("^Season"))

# Find the a tag with the href that follows
href = season.find_next('a', href=True)['href']
```

**Output:**

```
print(href)
mmz4281/2122/I1.csv
```